# GitとGitHubのコミットナンバーを揃える方法を教えてください

Tags: git, github

いつもお世話になっております。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

自分で管理しているサーバーにあるGitのコミットナンバーと、GitHubで管理しているコミットナンバーを揃えるためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

#### 【質問の補足】

1.

自分で管理している直近の`$ git log`は以下の通りです。

```
commit 26b33ecb18a8052c9190638f25e6d42a1307c0ff
Author: echizenya <hoge@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri May 31 16:46:47 2019 +0900

    header.phpの調整

commit 939de52ad7f58606cf0434ccdd8b6bab846d399b
Author: echizenya <hoge@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri May 31 16:03:43 2019 +0900

    WP Super Cacheの更新

commit b52ce1c244b045239d66439022830f939d0b94a3
Author: echizenya <hoge@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri May 31 16:02:52 2019 +0900

    header.phpの確認

commit 05c4881ee4a178da68514a2bc706a05e1f46d4d7
Author: echizenya <hoge@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed May 29 18:39:53 2019 +0900

    WP Super Cacheの更新
```

2.

一方、GitHubで管理している直近の`history`は以下のURLです。
https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota/commits/master/wp-content

3.

両者を比較すると、先頭の「header.phpの調整」のみコミットナンバーが異なります。これはheader.phpを誤って記述してしまい、「ごちゃごちゃ」と編集してコミットしたため、差異が生じたためです。

- 自分のサーバー → 26b33ec
- GitHub → a95576c

4.

現在、自分のサーバーからGitHubに向かってpushすると以下のエラーが発生します。

```
# git push origin master
To https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

5.

最終的には、自分のサーバー・GitHubともに`939de52ad7`で揃えたいと考えています。
その後、自分のサーバー側で新しく編集をした場合、GitHubに向かってpushして、サーバーで編集した内容をGitHubにも反映させたいと考えています。

---

以上、ご確認よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

他に`clone`している人がいない（＝履歴を書き換えても誰も困らない）ことが分かっているのであれば

```
git push -f origin master
```

してしまうのが手っ取り早いです。`-f`オプションはリモート（今回の場合はGitHub側）の履歴を無視して、ローカル（自分のサーバー）の内容を強制的に送り込むものです。

なお、コミットナンバーではなくコミットIDと呼びます。

Comment: sayuri さん。コメントありがとうございます。「大した変更ではない」・「他に`clone`している人がいない」ため、`git push -f origin master`を実行しました。その結果、Git・GitHubともにコミットIDを[26b33ec](https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota/commit/26b33ecb18a8052c9190638f25e6d42a1307c0ff#diff-e0526987d4c287d072ebdab374f4d549)で揃えることができました。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。